# A question about the space of functions the Ito integral is defined on

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}\,P)$ and the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$.

In Oksendal's book the Ito integral $I(f)(\omega)=\int_S^T f(t,\omega)dB_t(\omega)$ is defined on a space $\mathcal{V}(S,T)$. This is the space of functions such that

1. $(t,\omega)\to f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{F}$ measurable where $\mathcal{B}$ is the borel sigma algebra on $[0,\infty)$.
2. $f(t,\cdot)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted.
3. $E[\int_S^Tf^2(t,\omega)dt]<\infty$

Then the Ito integral of $f$ is defined by $$\int_S^T f(t,\omega)dB_t(\omega):=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_S^T \phi_n (t,\omega) dB_t(\omega)\,\,in\,\, L^2(P)$$ where $\{\phi_n\}$ is sequence of elementary functions such that $$E\Big[\int_S^T (f(t,\omega)-\phi_n(t,\omega))^2 dt\Big]\to 0 \,\,as\,\,n\to\infty$$

Now if we consider the space $\mathcal{W}$ of adapted elementary functions such that $E[\int_S^T\phi^2(t,\omega)dt]<\infty$ and define the an inner product $$\langle \phi,\psi\rangle_{\mathcal{W}}=E[\int_S^T\phi \psi dt]$$. Is $\mathcal{V}$ the closure of $\mathcal{W}$ with respect to the norm defined by the above inner product?

Comment: @saz yes, edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathcal{V}$ is the closure of $\mathcal{W}$ with respect to the norm induced by the inner product. You can find a proof for instance in the book *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by Schilling & Partzsch (Theorem 15.20 in the 2nd edition).

Comment: It took some time to get hold of this book. In this book it's proved that the closure of the space of simple functions is the space of  square integrable "progressively measurable" functions ($\mathcal{L}^2_T) $ which I think is a subspace of $\mathcal{V}$. Or is $\mathcal{V}$=$\mathcal{L}^2_T$?